# Missing URI template variable 'id' for method parameter of type String - Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, request-mapping

I have built a Spring MVC controller using the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(name = "/edit-soldier/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editSoldierForm(@PathVariable String id) throws FileNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("id:" + id);

        (snip ...)
    }
```

When I call the controller using the following URL : http://myurl/edit-soldier/Q65683623,

I get the following error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Missing URI template variable 'id' for method parameter of type String
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException: Missing URI template variable 'id' for method parameter of type String
```

I have tried to replace name by value or path but it doesn't work either (I am getting a 404 error this time).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `@PathVariable("id")`?

Comment: Same result with @PathVariable("id")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
@RequestMapping(name = "/edit-soldier/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit-soldier/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

> Note: Change **name** to **value**

or

```
@GetMapping("/edit-soldier/{id}")
```

Comment: When I change name to value as suggested, I get a 404 error. For some reasons, when I try to access url: http://myurl/edit-soldier/Q65683623, I get a 404 error saying that http://myurl/edit-soldier/edit-soldier.jsp can not be found.  Why is edit-soldier duplicated?

Comment: because you are returning edit-soldier.jsp in your code and it was not found. if you post the code. I can go further